# awk to not print a line after pattern was matched

Tags: awk

In my awk script I have pattern lines where I only want to perform some code, but not print the line.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN {stuff}
/bla/ {x=7}
END {stuff with x}
```

When my input file has 'bla' in it, it prints the line. I don't want that. I want the match to only trigger the setting of x. The awk script is executable and I run it with file argument from the cmd line.

```
../scripts/process.awk infile
```

The above echoes all the unwanted lines from infile.

Comment: On first look it doesn't seems to me that it prints that line which has bla in it, since you haven't given print in it. Could you please a bit of code snippet and then let us know? It will give us better understanding of code.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a carriage return between `/bla/` and `{x=7}`? The code you posted **will not** behave as you say it does.

Answer (score 0):

There was a close '}' in the BEGIN section in the wrong line. Once it  was fixed the issue went away.

Comment: That wouldn't explain the problem you describe but in any case you should delete your question now.